# Java interfaces error: Type is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <E>

Tags: java, generics, data-structures

I created a generic interface that I want to implement with a class. It's a basic stack data structure in which you can add and remove elements of type E.

```java
package makigas;

public interface ColaProceso<E> {
    
    void encolar(E e);
    
    void eliminar();
    
    E obtener();
}
```

And this is the class I've built to implement it:

```java
package makigas;

public class MiColaProceso<E> implements ColaProceso<E> {

    private class NodoProceso<T> {

        public T elemento;

        public NodoProceso<T> siguiente;
        
        public NodoProceso(T elemento) {
            this.elemento = elemento;
        }
    }
    
    private NodoProceso<E> cabeza, ultimo;

    public void encolar(E e) {
        NodoProceso<E> nuevoNodo = new NodoProceso<>(e);
        if (cabeza == null) {
            cabeza = nuevoNodo;
            ultimo = nuevoNodo;
        } else {
            ultimo.siguiente = nuevoNodo;
        }
        
    }

    public void eliminar() {
        if(cabeza != null) {
            NodoProceso<E> eliminar = cabeza;
            cabeza = cabeza.siguiente;
            eliminar.siguiente = null;
            if (cabeza == null) {
                ultimo = null;
            }
        }       
    }

    public E obtener() {
        if(cabeza == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return cabeza.elemento;
        }
    }
    
}
```

On top of the program, I get the following error I don't understand:

> The type ColaProceso is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments `<E>`

[image: The error message]

I have defined ColaProceso as a generic. I don't understand why the IDE tells me it's not a generic. What should I change to make it work?

Comment: Looks good. Try to remove `class` files and clear caches.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. I started a new project but still get the same error. I don't know what "clearing caches" means. My IDE (Eclipse) doesn't seem to have an option for that.